# GDB debugger problems - No source file named

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

For some reason I can't get gdb to recognize the files in my project when debugging. I've tried a variety of things, including downloading different version, etc. and the last thing I did was completely overwrite all of MingW with Twilight Dragon Media's Bundle Package.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? The odd thing was that when I first started using it, it was working fine, and then it suddenly stopped working.

I'm using Code::Blocks and I have the -g checked for the debug version of the project. I'm running on Windows Vista.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GDB locates source files by file path/name from the object module debug information. So if you moved your sources you should rebuild your project. This can also happen if you are running on a different host which has no visibility to your source at all.

The most important thing to remember is:

- **Debug information doesn't contain the source itself, but only the path where to find it. People often don't know this.**

Comment: So in a remote debug situation w/ gdbserver, how does one inform gdb of the local base directory for file locations?

Comment: Good question, this answer is 12 years ago :-) - but I think principle is the same - local client folders should match debug information that is used. In case of the answer I really was using this but here I cannot check now.